# Find the complex function f(z) given the following properties

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the complex function f(z) given the following properties

1. $(z^2+1)f(z)$ is entire
2. $f(z)$ is an even function
3. $Res(f;i) = i$
4. limit as abs(z) approaches infinity of f(z) = 1

So based on 3. it has an imaginary pole? So (z+i) ? This one is really difficult, please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first deduction we should be able to make is that $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z^2+1}$ where $g$ is holomorphic and even by the first two properties. We then known that $\frac{g(i)}{2i} = i$. Properties 2 and 4 demand that $g(z) = z^2 + b$ and so $g(i) = b - 1 = - 2$ implies $b = -1$. We thus have that $f(z) = \frac{z^2 - 1}{z^2 + 1}$.

Indeed, by inspection, $f$ satisfies the first, second and fourth properties. The third is verified since $\frac{i^2-1}{2i} = i$.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what these properties tell you about the function.

1. If $(z^2+1)f(z)$ is entire, what do you know about the the poles of $f$? Could it have a pole at $z=5$ for instance? Try and write down the possible denominators of $f$.
2. Kind of self explanatory, just check your final answer is even.
3. With your general forms of the denominator from 1, evaluate the residue at $i$ and see what else you need to add.
4. If you know the denominator, this give you constraints on the degree of the numerator.